# How to search whether this string is present as a value in mysql database in android using php?

Tags: php, android, mysql, search, android-asynctask

This is my code file
It will results true for all searched strings.I don't know why?
this is my JSON file on the server
https://vikasbajpayee.000webhostapp.com/villagesapi.php
Php code file
[link of php code](https://vikasbajpayee.000webhostapp.com/safal.txt)
Please tell me if anybody knows here .thanks in advance.

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(name!= null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(name)&&!name.equals("null"))
            new AsyncFetch(name).execute();
            else
                Toast.makeText(Checkout.this, "Please Enter Village name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

private class AsyncFetch extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(Checkout.this);
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    URL url = null;
    String searchQuery;

    public AsyncFetch(String searchQuery){
        this.searchQuery=searchQuery;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pdLoading.setMessage("\tLoading...");
        pdLoading.setCancelable(false);
        pdLoading.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {

            url = new URL("https://vikasbajpayee.000webhostapp.com/villagesapi.php");

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.toString();
        }
        try {

            // Setup HttpURLConnection class to send and receive data from php and mysql
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);

            // setDoInput and setDoOutput to true as we send and recieve data
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder().appendQueryParameter("searchQuery", searchQuery);
            String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();

            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(query);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
            conn.connect();

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return e1.toString();
        }

        try {

            int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();

            // Check if successful connection made
            if (response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                // Read data sent from server
                InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                String line;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(line);
                }

                // Pass data to onPostExecute method
                return (result.toString());

            } else {
                return("Connection error");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.toString();
        } finally {
            conn.disconnect();
        }


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        //this method will be running on UI thread
        pdLoading.dismiss();

        pdLoading.dismiss();
        if (result.equals("no rows")) {
            Toast.makeText(Checkout.this, "No Village exist with this name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            //success
            Toast.makeText(Checkout.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent=new Intent(Checkout.this,FinalCheckout.class);
            intent.putExtra("namedata",name);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }
}
}
```

I am searching for a "name" after button click in MySQL PHP database how can I do this.so that result would be searched the name on another activity .**this code is not working because it is getting true for all the searched strings(name here).it runs in all cases.**

Comment: In android Using PHP ? Where exactly is the issue . ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Android side:**

You are not actually searching for anything. You just fetch the data from a specific URL.Which gives you same data with every request.

you have to add some parameter to URL like this:

> example.com/villagesapi.php?name=myvillage

**Server side:**

And in your PHP script, you have to generate response according to the parameter that requested to it.
you can do it by like this:

```
if(isset($_GET['name'])) {
   //search from database where name = $_GET['name']
   //then echo json_encode(database response array)
}
```

and current problem is here,

```
if (result.equals("no rows")) {
        Toast.makeText(Checkout.this, "No Village exist with this name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

You are checking if the response is "no rows" then show a false message. But you always get a JSON string response which is not "no rows".
That's why for all request, you get true.

Note: In Android, you should not search for a string with *.contain()* method.You should parse the JSON string for the name.